# How to merge Sheets from different Excel in a Master Excel using a button / Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I want to know if there is a good approach to merge a single sheet from different Excel workbooks in a master Excel?

The structure looks like below:

I have 1 Folder with the Master Excel, and within this folder I do have also 5 subfolders calling (DE, IT, FR, UK and NL). Within each folder I have the exact same Excel, and now I want to grab the first sheet of each Excel and put it into the Master Excel.

I know about linking the sheets, but maybe is there a way to get a button and at some point it is just processing each sheet and merge it into the master?

Comment: Please take some time and read [ask]. Your question is quite broad and very unspecific which will lead into opinion based answers. Try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: You will need to show what you have tried so far, because Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Read How to Ask and try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Could you be more specific in your question? Do you want just the sheets to move to the master or do you want to combine the sheets so you're only moving one sheet to the master?